# How to upload media from S3 bucket URL

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi

Strapi provides `/upload` endpoint as mentioned in [Strapi documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#endpoints). If I have an S3 image URL like `https://something.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/filename.png`, how do I add that to the Strapi media library so I can attach that to different collections?

Answer (score 0):

After you add the plugin and follow the documentation, it will allow you to upload through the url and it will reference that file path.

Comment: Thanks. I see it's using `upload/proxy` but that just returns the image. Is there any way to create a media object from the URL itself programmatically without UI?